# How to Communiccate between JD Edwards Enterprise one 9.0 and .Net

Tags: c#-2.0, jdedwards

I have problem that how to communicate Jd Edwards Enterprise one 9.0 with .Net,and my project manager told me to look at the "fatclient" as it acts as a middle ware between these two,but there is no luck in my search,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Responding to this old post. Hopefully, this will help someone who has a similar need:

Take a look at our product LynX Business Integrator. It is Oracle Validated and it allows you to create integration processes **natively** in C# and publish it as a web service. So, you can write code like this:

```
private bool CallAddressBookBsfn(BusinessDocument businessDocument, Transaction transaction)
{     
  AddressBookMaster abm = businessDocument.document.input.AddressBook;

  // create an instance of the Address Book Master Business function
  // note the use of JDE Transactions
  AddressBookMasterMBF bsfn = new AddressBookMasterMBF(transaction);

  // set parameters - most of this code is auto-generated
  bsfn.DpmnAddressBookNumber.InValue = (long)abm.AddressNumber;
  bsfn.DpszSearchType.InValue = abm.AddressType;
  bsfn.DpszAlphaName.InValue = abm.Name;
  bsfn.DpszAddressLine1.InValue = abm.AddressLine1;
  bsfn.DpszAddressLine2.InValue = abm.AddressLine2;
  bsfn.DpszAddressLine3.InValue = abm.AddressLine3;
  bsfn.DpszAddressLine4.InValue = abm.AddressLine4;
  bsfn.DpszPostalCode.InValue = abm.ZipCodePostal;
  bsfn.DpszCity.InValue = abm.City;
  bsfn.DpszState.InValue = abm.State;
  bsfn.DpszCountry.InValue = abm.Country;
  bsfn.DpcActionCode.InValue = 'A';
  bsfn.DpcUpdateMasterFile.InValue = '1';

  // execute the business function
  if (bsfn.Execute() != BusinessFunctionResult.Success)
  {
    // get errors
    return false;
  }

  // assign output
  businessDocument.document.output.AddressNumber = bsfn.DpmnAddressBookNumber.OutValue;
  businessDocument.document.output.AddressNumberSpecified = true;
  return true;
}
```

Take a look at our YouTube Channel at http://www.youtube.com/user/aelliuslynx and our product page at http://www.aellius.com/products/lynx-business-integrator

Answer (score 0):

I am using old version 8.0 and if by "communication" you mean to be able from a .NET application to run JDE BSFN directly, then i am gonna dissapoint you but there isn't any way i know of.

Maybe things have changed in 9.0 but i doubt it.

Personally whenever i want to communicate with our JDE (AS400 based) i am using:

Frontend

-.NET Web Api services 
-C# winforms apps
-ASP.NET

Backend

-Custom Dlls for Business logic and Data Access Layers.

Comment: Do you have any samples you can share? I am just starting to investigate JDE with its 9.1 demo version